# NDSolve error for system of two non-linear equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I'm trying to solve this system of non-linear ODE's
$$\left\{y'(s) \left(x''(s) y'(s)-x'(s) y''(s)\right)=0,\mu  x'(s) \left(x'(s) y''(s)-x''(s) y'(s)\right)=g \lambda  \left(x'(s)^2+y'(s)^2\right)^{3/2}\right\}$$
where for instance $g=\mu=\lambda=1$

The code with set boundary conditions is

```
NDSolveValue[{-2 Derivative[1][y][s] (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
       s] + Derivative[1][x][s] (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[s] == 
    0, (-2 Derivative[1][x][s] Derivative[1][y][s] (
        x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[s] + 
      2 Derivative[1][x][s]^2 (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[s] + 
      Derivative[1][y][s] (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[s]) == 
    2 (Derivative[1][x][s]^2 + Derivative[1][y][s])^(3/2), 
   DirichletCondition[x[s] == s/2, True], 
   DirichletCondition[x[s] == 1, True]}, {x[s], y[s]}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

I get a `NDSolveValue::femnlmdor` error:
[image]

I don't really understand where this error is coming from, what's wrong with my system begin second order so long as it has sufficient boundary conditions. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: could you explain better what the BC are? You have 1D problem. What are the dependent variables values are boundaries?

Comment: There is one independent variable `s` and two dependant `x` and `y`. The boundary conditions are specified at `x[0]==0`, `x[1]==1/2`, `y[0]==1` and `y[1]==1`

Comment: if you do not solve using FEM, the error is `Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve 
will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations`. It is better to write your code using separate statements so easy to read. `mu = 1; g = 1; lambda = 1;
ode1 = y'[s] (x''[s]*y'[s] - x'[s]*y''[s]) == 0;
ode2 = mu*x'[s]*(x'[s]*y''[s] - x''[s]*y'[s]) == 
   g*lambda*(x'[s]^2 + y'[s]^2)^(3/2);
bc = {x[0] == 0, x[1] == 1/2, y[0] == 1 , y[1] == 1};
NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, bc}, {x[s], y[s]}, {s, 0, 1}]`

Comment: `y'[s] (x''[s]*y'[s] - x'[s]*y''[s]) == 0` has two possible solutions.  The first is `y[s]` constant, which when substituted into the second equation also yields `x[s]` constant.  The second is `(x''[s]*y'[s] - x'[s]*y''[s]) == 0`, which when substituted into the second equations again yields both `x[s]` and `y[s]` constant.

Comment: If you want to make use of the FEM then you'd need to rewrite this equation in `Inactive` form. See this message page; FEMDocumentation/ref/message/InitializePDECoefficients/femnlmdor